# How to pass value from activity to frament on backbutton press in android studio

Tags: android

I have `fragment`, from that fragment i go to 1 `activity` and do some calculation then i press back button and that value again pass to that `fragment` so how i can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start activity from fragment you can start as below:-

```
   startActivityForResult(new Intent(context,NewActivity.class),1);
```

And when you pressed back button then `onBakcPressed` method

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("data", "value_here")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

In your fragment `override` `onActivityResult` method :-

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String strEditText = data.getStringExtra("data");
         }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use `onActivityResult()` of fragment and in `onBackpress()` of activity pass the data in `setResult()`.

I hope this will help you.